# How to show $g(x)=\frac{4^x+x^2-\ln(2)\cdot x-1}{\tan(2x)}$ is continuous at $x = 0$ for $g(0) := \ln(\sqrt{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> $g(x)$ is defined on the Intervalls $(\frac{-\pi}{2}, 0) \cup(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

I've tried doing it by using L'Hôpital but $\sin(x)$ gets into the denominator and I can't get rid off it.

Comment: Hint: $4^x+x^2-\ln 2.x-1 = ((2)^{2x}-1) + 2x.\frac{(x-\ln 2)}2$

Comment: @WhatAMesh What makes you think $\lim g(x)$ is undefined?

Comment: @Jam $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x) = \frac{4^0+0-0-1}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined

Comment: @WhatAMesh Actually, you can have a limit defined at a point, even if the function has a discontinuity there. Think about $l=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{x}$. We can show that $l=\lim 1 = 1$, even though we can't do $\frac00$. This is why we use limits :)

Comment: @Jam I'd approach it with L'Hôpital and take the derivative because if I were to plug in 0, I'd get $\frac{0}{0}$. Im sure it exists but how do I find it is the question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: By writing $\tan(\cdot)=\frac{\sin(\cdot)}{\cos(\cdot)}$ and rearranging terms, we can show that:

$$\frac{4^x+x^2-\ln(2) x-1}{\tan(2x)}=\cos(2x)\left(\color{blue}{\frac{4^x-1}{\sin(2x)}}\right)+\cos (2x)\left(x-\ln 2\right)\left(\color{red}{\frac{x}{\sin(2x)}}\right)$$

So now all we need to find is $\lim\frac{4^x-1}{\sin(2x)}$ and $\lim\frac{x}{\sin(2x)}$.

---

**Hint 2**:

We can simplify the problem further by stating $\frac{x}{\sin(2x)}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}$ and using the substitution $2x\mapsto u$. so the limit becomes:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin(2x)}=\frac{1}{2}\:\color{green}{\lim_{u\to0}\frac{u}{\sin u}}$$

This limit is very famous and can be proven geometrically. We can then state $\lim\frac{4^x-1}{\sin(2x)}=\frac{2^{2x}-1}{\sin(2x)}=\left(\frac{2^{2x}-1}{2x}\right)\left(\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}\right)$. We can simplify the bracketed term on the left hand side as $\frac{2^{2x}-1}{2x}=\frac{e^{(2\ln2) x}-1}{2x}$. With the substitutions $2 x \mapsto u$ and $(2\ln2) x \mapsto v$, we can split the limit in two to show:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4^x-1}{\sin(2x)}=\ln2\:\color{brown}{\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{e^v-1}{v}}\:\color{green}{\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u}{\sin u}}$$

There are many ways to prove both of these limits, including ways that avoid l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: I can't find the limits by using L'Hôpital, because as soon as $sin(a)$ is below the fraction it will always be there, do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: @WhatAMesh The formula for L'Hôpital's rule is $\lim\frac{f}{g}=\lim\frac{f'}{g'}$. If we set $g(x)=\sin(x)$ then what is $g'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin(x)$?

Comment: Oh, im so dumb, I always derived the whole thing, thanks for ur patience

Comment: @WhatAMesh Nah, you're not dumb :). And sure, no worries

Comment: @WhatAMesh For posterity, I've added a second part to my answer that gives a way of avoiding l'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, l'Hôpital is not really complicated here:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4^x\ln4+2x-\ln2}{2(1+\tan^22x)}
$$

Without it, rewrite your function as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{4^x-1}{x}\frac{2x}{\tan2x}+\frac{2x}{\tan2x}\frac{x-\ln2}{2}
$$
Now recall that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{\tan2x}=1
$$
so you just need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4^x-1}{x}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\ln2}{2}
$$
The former is the derivative at $0$ of $x\mapsto 4^x$, so it's $\ln4=2\ln2$. Hence you get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\ln4-\frac{\ln2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\ln2
$$

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you say:

> $\lim _{x→0}g(x)=\frac{4^0+0−0−1}{0}=\frac00 $ which is undefined

This is exactly the opposite of how limits work.

- You should be aware that the limit as $x \rightarrow a$ can be defined even if $f(x)$ is not defined. In fact this happens seemingly rarely because if it *does* happen we just conveniently enough define $f(a)$ as that limit, i.e., we replace $f$ with a new $f$ that is extended by one point.
- So the substitution you did does not make sense. The fractional expression of $g$ is not defined at $0$, so it is not clear why you try to substitute it. If you did, you would get "undefined," which tells you absolutely nothing, as you already know from the above bullet point.
- If, for some reason, you *did* know that the limit was undefined, you would *immediately* know $g$ is not continuous. But you did conclude that, and the you tried finding some other way to show $g$ is continuous. What you *should* have done is figure out why that logic is wrong, or double check it is right which would make the problem wrong.
- Derivatives only exist for continuous functions so it's not clear how you plan to take the derivate of a function you are not sure is continuous.

Try to rework your work so far and see what you get.

Comment: Well I have to say it differently, what I'm trying to say is, that I can use L'Hôpital because it is $\frac{0}{0}$ when I plug in the 0. And that doesn't work because the derivatives get too complicated. One way or another I have to manipulate the term so that I can evaluate it

Comment: @WhatAMesh you kinda ignored my answer so good luck.